# Custom HttpHandler to redirect to different websites for single signon experience

Tags: asp.net, redirect

Here's my situation:

I have a number of separate websites (which have the same basic format but different authentication logins) - not one website with several folders with apps, separate web applications.

I have a client whose site has links to these websites, but when they click on these links they have to login/authenticate with each one.

So they have links to my sites like:

```
ricksite1.com?customerid=1
ricksite2.com?customerid=5
ricksite3.com?customerid=1000
```

To avoid all of this manual authentication, they want to implement single sign on using a federated identity provider, so that when they click on these links they don't have to manually authenticate each time.

Putting aside the federated mechanism for the moment, I decided that I would prototype simply and create a website with a custom http handler that would redirect the request to the appropriate website based on a querystring parameter called site.

So theoretically I could hit this new site as follows, and it would redirect to ricksite1.com:

redirectsite.com?site=1&customerid=1 would redirect to ricksite1.com?customerid=1

When I try this, I get the error: Invalid path for child request 'ricksite1.com'. A virtual path is expected.

How can I fix this?

Here's the http handler:

```
public class RedirectHttpHandler:IHttpHandler
    {
        private Dictionary<string, Uri> Sites = new Dictionary<string, Uri>
            {
                {"1", new Uri("http://ricksite1.com")},
                {"2", new Uri("http://ricksite2.com")},
                {"3", new Uri("http://ricksite3.com")}
            };

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            string site = context.Request.QueryString["site"];

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(site) && Sites.Keys.Contains(site))
            {
                context.Server.Transfer(Sites[site].AbsoluteUri, true);
            }
        }
   }
```

with the config file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="*"
        type="RedirectSite.RedirectHttpHandler, RedirectSite, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
    </httpHandlers>

  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
context.Response.Redirect(Sites[site].AbsoluteUri, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

This way mush better

```
   HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(Sites[site].AbsoluteUri, true);
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation why will this be a better solution ?